# How to Learn PWA in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio

Can Any one Please Advise me on this Topics:-

1) How to learn PWA in magento 2 ?

2) How to integerate PWA With Magento Custom Theme ?

3) How PWA Works in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer PWA devedoc Documentation. I am sure you will get enough knowledge about the integration and PWA-studio and Custom Theme. 
Here is the link :

> https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/

Or you can join Magento official Slack channel for PWA in which you can do Q and A.

> https://magentocommeng.slack.com/

Use Hashtag #pwa.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Devdocs for learning PWA studio

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pwa/

Please refer this blog for install PWA

[Install PWA studio](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/)